# Select a value from table and reserve it

Tags: mysql, sql

Low level question but, I understand that you can select elements from a table using:

```
$sql = "SELECT blah FROM TABLE WHERE this = 'something' ";
```

But when I try to select a specific value from my table, where let's say a user has no tries left so if I try to grab how many tries they have left with:

```
$sql = "SELECT tries FROM table WHERE user = 'something'";
```

How would I grab that value specifically if it was 5 or 9?  I tried setting a variable equal to something I $sql off my table but it doesn't grab the value.

### Edit

I have a database that has a table called `Item` which contains: id, name, value, and `stock` of a particular item. If a user wants to order that item I will first check it if's in `stock` with a function, to see if it is not in stock then a error message is printed, otherwise **accept** the order.

Extremely primitive since I'm just trying to get grab the stock value first.

```
$query = $_GET['query']; //id I get from the specified item
echo 'the id is: ' .$query.''; //test purposes

$mysql_handle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die("Error connecting to database server");

mysql_select_db($dbname, $mysql_handle)
    or die("Error selecting database: $dbname");

$sql1 = "SELECT item_stock FROM chat-db.Item WHERE id = '".$query."'";
echo '' .$sql2. ''; //test purposes
```

whats the correct way to assign the value from that specific stock to a variable?

Comment: could you show the table definition, some sample data and desired output

Comment: I have a database that has a table called Item which contains: id, name, value, and stock of a particular item.  If a user wants to order that item I will first check it if's in stock with a function, to see if it is not in stock then a error message is printed, otherwise accept the order.

Comment: like `select stock from item where id=333`

Comment: but you need concurrency control, because with stock=7 and two people wanting 5 at the same time, well you see where the problem is. A manual page ---> [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-lock-modes.html)

Comment: I tried '$sql = "SELECT stock FROM Item WHERE id=blah";'
but it doesn't grab the value when I test it by printing the value out with an echo call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to grab rows with a set of possible values you can use 'IN' such as:

**Get all columns from users table where users have 5 or 9 tries:**

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE tries IN('5', '9');` or

If you want to select where the user has no tries left, assuming the tries column is a numeric type you can look for rows with 0 tries:

**Get all columns from Item table where stock is 0:**

`SELECT * FROM db_inv.Item WHERE stock = '0';`

**Get all columns from users table where tries is 0:**

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE tries = '0';`

As for your php code you should be able to do the following:

```
$query = $_GET['query']; //id I get from the specified item
echo 'the id is: ' . $query; //test purposes

$mysql_handle = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Error connecting to database server");

$sql1 = "SELECT item_stock FROM chat-db.Item WHERE id = '".$query."'";

$results = mysqli_query($mysql_handle, $sql1);

if (!empty($results) && mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo $rec['item_stock'];
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I grab that value once I selected it though?  Like if I wanted to compare the value I just selected later on by: $value = 'what i just selected'

Comment: What tool are you using for querying your database? Or include the code where you query the db and I can tell you.

Comment: I've edited my post to include a snippet of my code.

Comment: I included a template of a query procedures in my answer.